# Transferência JSON para CodeIgniter via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

Não estou conseguindo passar uma string no formato `JSON` para um `controller` do CodeIgniter via AJAX.

A string JSON:

```
var avaliacao= {"avaliacao":[{"pergunta":"Qual sua idade?"}[{"resposta_certa":"99","resposta_err1":"11","resposta_err2":"15",
"resposta_err3":"14","resposta_err4":"27"}]]}
```

O JS:

```
var controller = 'endereco/controller';
var base_url = 'dominio/do/site';

function grava_avaliacao(){ 

    jQuery.ajax({
        url : base_url + '/' + controller + '/add',
        type : 'POST', 
        data : avaliacao,
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(data){ 
                        alert(data);
                    }
    });
}
```

O controller:

```
public function add(){
    var_dump(json_decode($this->input->post('avaliacao')));
}
```

Comment: Esse json esta correto? Tente o jsonlint.com ou outro para testar, pode ser isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify()` para converter seu objeto em uma string Json no atributo `data` da função `ajax`.

O parâmetro `data` aceita uma string ou um objeto, mas ele não converte automaticamente para Json e sim para o formato de *query string*. É uma confusão comum.

Exemplo:

```js
jQuery.ajax({
    url : base_url + '/' + controller + '/add',
    type : 'POST', 
    data : { 'avaliacao': JSON.stringify(avaliacao) },
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function(data){ 
                    alert(data);
                }
});
```

---

**Update**

Conforme os comentários, havia um problema também na URL, pois o método do controlador nem era executado. Então, deve-se sempre verificar se a URL usada em comandos Ajax é a correta, principalmente ao usar frameworks que abstraem o *path*.

Comment: Alterei o js, mas não tenho retorno.

Comment: @Away Ajustei o código. Veja se funciona agora. Havia esquecido de que o parâmetro precisa de um nome.

Comment: Continuo sem receber retorno. Alterei o código, envio mas não tenho retorno algum.

Comment: @Away Se você fizer `var_dump($this->input->post('avaliacao'));`, o que aparece na saída?

Comment: Continuo não tendo nada. Envio e não tenho nenhum retorno, chequei a chamada da funçõ e está funcionando. Acredito que o problema esteja entre o controller e o js.

Comment: @Away Só para eu entender bem. O código Javascript é executado e uma requisição chega no servidor. O `var_dump` chega a ser executado, mas exibe um conteúdo vazio ou nulo. É isso mesmo?

Comment: A requisição não está nem chegando no servidor, se estivesse estaria me retornando ao menos um conteúdo null...

Comment: @Away Se não está chegando no controller, o problema não é relacionado ao conteúdo, mas sim à URL utilizada. Sem ver a configuração do framework e o código Ajax completo é impossível dizer o que está errado. Olhe [um exemplo](http://runnable.com/UXczcazDrMMiAAGl/how-to-do-ajax-in-codeigniter-for-php) e revise a requisição feita pelo navegador (F12 / ferramenta do desenvolvedor) para ver se a URL que o seu código gera é a que o Code Igniter espera receber.

Comment: O problema estava mesmo na URL... acertei e aqui e funcionou. vlw